# Escaping Quotes inside new C# 6 String Syntax

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I'm really excited about the new features in C# 6, including the new string syntax:

```
var fullName = $"My Name is {FirstName} {LastName}";
```

However, I can't figure out how to escape quotes inside the braces to do the follow:

```
bool includePrefix = true;

var fullName = $"My name is {includePrefix ? "Mr. " : ""}{FirstName} {LastName}";
```

C# 6 doesn't like that. I've had to revert to using `String.Format` in that second case.  Is it possible to escape quotes using the new syntax?

Update: Yes, I have tried using the `\` escape, but it's not recognized.

Comment: Write a property that does the property string logic and then just use that in the string instead.

Comment: @asawyer I am aware of several workarounds, including one I stated in my question. I'd just like to know if escaping is possible inside this new syntax.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx#Anchor_1

Answer (score 94, accepted):

wrap your logic inside parentheses, *inside* the brackets:

```
var fullName = $"My name is {(includePrefix ? "Mr. " : "")}{FirstName} {LastName}";
```

Answer (score 20):

Regularly to escape quotes you need to use a slash (i.e. `\"`).

However, this is not the issue here, as you don't need to escape, you're just missing parentheses over the expression.

This works:

```
bool includePrefix = true;
var fullName = $"My name is {(includePrefix ? "Mr. " : "")}{FirstName} {LastName}";
```